# Python leave 10% branches with max weight NetworkX graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have graph and counted network density, and now I should keep only the branches that have maximum weight ( first 10% of network density, fo example 20 branches with biggest weight from 200 ). I cant find how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is slightly confusing, so, I am happy to amend the response if more information surfaces later on.

> I have graph and counted network density,

By which I am assuming that you have an undirected (?) weighted network. And consequently, network density (for the weighted case) would be calculated by summing the weights of the edges and dividing them by the number of possible edges (|V|*(|V|-1) where V is the edge set and |.| denotes the cardinality of the set). If this is what you have, let's call the calculated network density Q.

> I should keep only the branches that have maximum weight ( first 10% of network density

So, now, you want to isolate those edges **whose weight, makes up 10% of Q**. Let's call this `Qfrac=Q*(10/100.0)` To do this, in general, first sort the edges by weight in descending order and then start accumulating their density contribution until the accumulated sum is equal (or exceeds) Qfrac.

In code and assuming that G is the graph and each edge has a `weight` attribute:

```
edgesSorted =  sorted(G.edges(data = True), key=lambda x:x[2]['weight'], reverse=False)
k=0
acc=0.0
NposCons = float(G.number_of_nodes() * (G.number_of_nodes()-1))
while (acc<Qfrac):
    acc+=(edgesSorted[k][2]['weight']/NposCons
    k+=1
edgeExtract = edgesSorted[0:k]
```

BUT!

> fo example 20 branches with biggest weight from 200 )

This, is slightly different. In this case, you don't seem to need the density calculation, all you want is to select **10% of the edges with high weights from the 200 edges that the graph contains in total**. This is  dealt with slightly differently:

Again, in code and with similar assumptions as above:

```
edgesSorted =  sorted(G.edges(data = True), key=lambda x:x[2]['weight'], reverse=False)
edgeExtract = edgesSorted[0:int(round(G.number_of_edges() * (10/100.0)))]
```

Hope this helps.